# Box-box collision detection with PyOpenGL and Pygame at 3d

Tags: python, collision-detection, pyopengl

I'm writing a player class that, among other things, has mesh attributes (I use the [py3d library](https://github.com/ax-va/PyOpenGL-Pygame-Stemkoski-Pascale-2021) and the mesh class from it) and collider (a class that I need to implement myself). The collider is a simple cube and should have a method to determine whether it collided with another collider-cube or not. I have a class that allows you to rotate and move 3d objects, I inherit the collider from it. The main problem is precisely to write a collision check function

I tried to use the methods built into Pygame to detect collisions, but it didn't work, because when the camera is removed, the collider remains the same size, and it can't be rotated. I'm bad at math, and all the guides I found were in C.[game example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK1tW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect box-box collisions in 3D using PyOpenGL and Pygame is to use the Bullet physics engine. Bullet is a 3D physics engine that can be used to detect collisions, apply forces, and simulate the motion of rigid bodies. To use Bullet, you would need to implement the collider class as a Bullet body, and then use the Bullet functions to detect collisions between the collider objects. You can also use the Bullet functions to rotate and move the colliders, which will allow you to keep the same size collider regardless of the camera position.

Here's a link to a tutorial on how to integrate bullet
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-a-physics-library/